# C++ Conditional operator performance

Tags: c++, performance, conditional-statements

I've a conditional statement `expensive_foo()` which is false in 99.9% cases. And I have a conditional statement `bar` which is true in ~50% cases.

And I want some action be done if both statements are true. So I almost certainly know that `expensive_foo()` is false and I want to check it only if `bar` is true.

Will the code below check the `expensive_foo()` ONLY if `bar` is true? Or it will check `expensive_foo()` every time?

```
if ( bar && expensive_foo() )
{
    ...
}
```

Or I need to make a structure like this:

```
if ( bar )
{
    if ( expensive_foo() )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Logical boolean operators short-circuit, unless overloaded, aka *yes*, `foo` will only be checked if `bar` is true. Though, I have to admit, I don't see the performance benefit from saving a single boolean comparision..

Comment: Branch-prediction would be better with the 1st example i think.

Comment: @Xeo `foo` is a result of some heavy method.

Comment: Well, that would have been smart to put into the question.

Comment: So, do you do `bar && heavy_method_yielding_foo()` or `foo = heavy_method(); if(bar && foo) ...`?

Comment: Those are *important details* and without those, answering the question is basically impossible (or the answers will not be what you really wanted).

Comment: @Kolyunya [SO] cares about the quality of your question. Even if you don't.

Comment: Because after your edit, it didn't apply anymore. And then you edited back.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore actually it does apply, why not?

Comment: Because if you put the expensive condition first... it's just not the same.

Comment: @Kolyunya That's an expression. Statements usually end with semicolons.

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry for my bad question formulation

Comment: @Xeo performance benefit can be immense as the conditions might be lengthy function calls.

Comment: @IvoTops: Yeah, but that was not clear from the original question, which is where my comment stems from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logical AND operator `&&` is short-circuited, which means that it is guaranteed the second operand is evaluated if and only if the first one is evaluated as `true`. The conditions `if (bar && foo)` and `if (bar) if (foo)` are identical.

Given that `foo` is expensive to compute, you should almost definitely check `bar` first. Even though `bar` won't be predictable by the branch predictor very well, that's a minor effect compared to the computation of `foo`.

Thus the structure should probably be:

```
if (bar)
{
    if (bool const foo = compute())   // expensive
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that all of those constructions mean that we may or may not call `compute()`. If you require the function call unconditionally, then you should make it the *first* check. In that case, the successful branch prediction on the result should be exploited.

Comment: Which is only true semantically, not performance wise. If bar and foo are not side-effecting the compiler can still reorder them causing a performance penalty.

Comment: @usr: I'm pretty sure it can't.

Comment: @DeadMG the compiler can do anything which does not change the behavior of the program according to the standard. If no behavioral change is observable the compiler can do this. (The OP edited the post though telling us that foo is actually foo_expensive(). This makes my point moot, although it was correct).

Comment: @DeadMG depends. If they have side-effects the compiler can't reorder the side-effects. Otherwise, you can't observe the difference.

Comment: @Kolyunya: No. `if (bar && compute())` is identical to `if (bar) { if (compute()) { /* .. */ } }`. It's safe and fine. I just thought you might like to store the result of `compute()`, or have an `else` branch. But if you don't, feel free to put everything into one single condition.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks! And it seems to me, you've made a mistake: not `false` but `true` in the first sentence.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Err... yes! Argh. I'm not with it today. It's the opposite for `||` and for `&&`. Whichever one makes sense! :-)

Comment: Some processors can conditionally execute instructions.  So the impact to the execution would be negligible for simple conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

Both codes will check `foo` only in case `bar` is true. In first case this is guaranteed by the language lazy boolean expression evaluation (which actually could be explicitly turned off in some compilers, but is ON by default).

Comment: I'd be surprised if any compiler allowed you to turn short-circuit evaluation off; that would break a lot of code.

Comment: You can turn it off by saying `bar & foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but I'm questioning the premise.

If you are querying a predicate that is false 99.9% of the time, that is analogous to doing linear search in a list of 2000 entries, where the item you are looking for could be anywhere with roughly equal probability.

In that case, typically one would try to organize the list differently so as to do a O(logN) (or better) search instead of O(N).
I don't know if you can do this, but that is where I would focus.

When a question is being asked with highly skewed probability, that can be a big speedup opportunity, if one can un-skew it.
(Assuming a big % of time is spent in this activity. If not, the point is moot.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if the optimized assembly for both wasn't exactly the same.  expensive_foo() will never be called if bar is false.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a comment that the compiler can re-order operations and I'm inclined to that opinion.
The efforts to improve automatic parallelization of the sequential programs has resulted in somewhat better compilers and it helps a programmer to avoid complex routines of parallelization from their programs. 
The compiler could re-order the operations provided the re-ordering does not violate/worsen the locality or in a broad sense doesn't violate the actual intention of the of the program.

But I doubt the fact that the compiler would try to re-order a conditional statement
like :

```
  if ( bar && expensive_foo() )
```

If the less expensive Boolean function is put at the beginning, it is certain that we can save some time.